# how can i use setState in state object within functional component?

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate, react-functional-component

if i'm using state object within functional component like this:

```
  const state = {
    stage: useState(1),
    players: useState([]),
    result: useState(""),
  };
```

then how would i be able to define the setState function and use it ? thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you use the useReducer Hook if you have a complex state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd prefer having a single state object, with 3 properties, using a single `useState` call.

```
let [game,updateGame] = useState({stage: 1, players: [], result: ''});
```

I'd hesitate using the `state` as a variable name, as it may be confusing, when another developer looks at the code for the 1st time.

You can update it as follows:

```
function goToNextLevel() {
    updateGame(game=> {
        if(game.stage == 12) {
            return {...game, result: 'win'};
        } else {
            return {...game, stage: game.stage+1};
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are three completely separate and unique states, and they must be set individually.

`useState` returns an array with two items. The first item is the states value, and the second item is a function used to set that state.

So with this `state` object, you would get the state value with:

```
state.stage[0] // get "stage" value
```

And set the state with:

```
state.stage[1](newStage) // set "stage" value
```

---

But that's not how react applications are typically structured because trying to remember if you should use `[0]` or `[1]` is pretty ugly.

Instead, this is typically laid out like this:

```
const [stage, setStage] = useState(1),
const [players, setPlayers] = useState([])
const [result, setResult] = useState("")
```

And now reading state is as easy as `stage` and setting it as easy as `setStage(newStage)`.

Answer (score 0):

We can update state value in the following way

**import hooks**

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
```

**State Value**

```
const [ expand, setExpand ] = useState(false)
```

**Update Method**

```
const handleExpand = useCallback(() => {
    setExpand(prevState => !prevState)
})
```